# Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 in Docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dbus, java

I'm trying to install OpenJDK8 in a docker ubuntu container but i'm still receiving this error:

```
(gconftool-2:4389): GConf-WARNING **: 
Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the DISPLAY variable to a X server (the one on your host for example), but installing openjdk 8 can be done without an X server.
You can take the official `java:openjdk-8` image as an example of how to do that, its Dockerfile is here : https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/master/8-jdk/Dockerfile